# Is there a synonym for " of Unworldly Origin "?

Tags: synonyms

" of Unworldly Origin" is one of the chapters in
**The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warren** book
So, I was wondering if there is another word or synonym (correct me if I'm wrong)
For it ?
Excuse my bad English, this is the first English book that I'm reading.

Comment: is there a specific context/sentence? Because there are two things you could interpret from the description 'of unworldly origin-' one is literal (alien, extraterrestrial, etc.)- and others are more figurative, meaning that they are somehow of ethereal origin (supernatural, unearthly).

Answer (score 2):

It's worth looking at two separate usage charts for this. First, [here's the nineteenth century...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other-worldly%20origin%2Cunworldly%20origin&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]

...and [here's the same for the twentieth century...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other-worldly%20origin%2Cunworldly%20origin&year_start=1910&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]

In short, for the past century and more, the most common "synonym" for the Victorian expression ***unworldly origin*** is just ***other-worldly origin***.

Note that *both* terms (but more particularly the earlier version) are primarily used to distinguish the "earthly, natural" world from "supernatural, spiritual" environments. The *literal* implications of, say, ***extraterrestrial*** weren't often relevant to most writers in the distant past. And nobody spoke of ***exoplanets*** or [***panspermia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia).